# Check if user signed in before any action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to execute some function before any controller action to check if the user is signed in. I am using `devise` so that I can use `is_signed_in?`, but I have to put if else condition to every method in the controller.

What I want is to have something like this:

```html
#some_controller.rb
before_action :is_signed_in?

def is_signed_in?
   if !user_signed_in?
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
   else 
      ..proceed to the action intended to call
   end
end
```

So I want this method to execute before any action (or some set of actions) and redirect to sign in if false or let that action to be executed if true.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is shipped with some useful built-in helpers.

In your case, one that interested you is `authenticate_user!`. Take a look at [controller filters and helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) in Devise documentation.

You can filter your actions in your controller with this method to ensure only logged-in users can process a given action or all actions in a controller, else if user isn't logged-in then he is redirect to login page.

```
before_action :authenticate_user!

before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show]
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also create your own helper method.

In your `users_controller.rb`, create a before_action filter

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user
    ...
end
```

and in your `session_helper.rb`

```
module SessionHelper
   # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
   def logged_in?
       !current_user.nil?
   end

   # Confirms a logged-in user.
   def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
         flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
         redirect_to login_url
      end
   end

end
```

Comment: Bump for using the `unless` keyword. No reason to use bangs and sacrifice readability.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check whether user is signed for every action in the application, you have to put the filter in the application controller. You can do this for a specific controller also.

You can use the `devise` method:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  ...
end
```

You can create your own filter also:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :my_authentication
  ... 
  def my_authentication
     if user_signed_in? 
        # do something ...
     else 
        # do something else ...
     end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/)? You can use existing filter:

```
  class SomeController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    ...
  end
```

if not, create your filter in application controller and add it to your needed controllers:

```
  class SomeController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :my_auth_filter
    ...
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this method to your ApplicationController

```
def user_is_logged_in
    if !session[:current_user]
        redirect_to login_path
    end
end
```

Use it before invoking any actions. Like so,

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :user_is_logged_in
  ...
end
```